# In PHP, can you instantiate an object and call a method on the same line?

Tags: php, oop

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
$method_result = new Obj()->method();
```

Instead of having to do:

```
$obj = new Obj();
$method_result = $obj->method();
```

The result doesn't actually matter to me in my specific case.  But, is there a way to do this?

Comment: btw, if you are not using 5.4 (which you probably aren't), you can define a helper function which just returns an object to chain stuff ... function with($obj) { return $obj; } (picked the trick up from laravel :P) .. then you can do with(new Obj)->method()

Comment: BTW, if you find yourself doing this often, its worth considering whether `my_method` should instead be declared `static`.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The feature you have asked for is available from PHP 5.4. Here is the list of new features in PHP 5.4:

https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/migration54.new-features

And the relevant part from the new features list:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. `(new Foo)->bar().`

Comment: Note that this also means you can do `(new Foo)->property` if you wanted to.

Comment: Note that you cannot assign properties in this way yet. (new Foo)->property = 'property';

Comment: @CMCDragonkai logically that makes sense; the object only exists for the duration of the statement `(new Foo)->property` - the value you are storing has nowhere to go because the object will no longer exist after that as it's not stored anywhere.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You can assign properties this way by calling the corresponding **setters**, all you need to do is to add `return $this` to your setters. This will also allow you to chain setters.

Comment: I have a question. Is there any benefit to declaring the object on a separate line and saving it to a variable, other than being able to reuse the object?

Comment: @TylerSwartzenburg If you want to use your object, then yes, you'll need an actual reference to it. Why even instantiate a class if you don't want to use it?

Comment: Thank you for this. New to OOP in PHP and this helps clean up my code a lot.

Comment: @Matt: If you find yourself doing this often, its worth considering whether `my_method` should instead be declared `static`.

Answer (score 40):

You cannot do what you are asking ; but you can "cheat", using the fact that, in PHP, you can have a function that has the same name as a class ; those names won't conflict.

So, if you  declared a class like this :

```
class Test {
    public function __construct($param) {
        $this->_var = $param;
    }
    public function myMethod() {
        return $this->_var * 2;
    }
    protected $_var;
}
```

You can then declare a function that returns an instance of that class -- and has exactly the same name as the class :

```
function Test($param) {
    return new Test($param);
}
```

And now, it becomes possible to use a one-liner, like you asked -- only thing is you are calling the function, thus not using new :

```
$a = Test(10)->myMethod();
var_dump($a);
```

And it works : here, I'm getting :

```
int 20
```

as output.

And, better, you can put some phpdoc on your function :

```
/**
 * @return Test
 */
function Test($param) {
    return new Test($param);
}
```

This way, you'll even have hints in your IDE -- at least, with Eclipse PDT 2.x ; see the screeshot :

[image]

---

**Edit 2010-11-30 :** Just for information, a new RFC has been submitted, a few days ago, that proposes to add this feature to one of the future versions of PHP.

See : **Request for Comments: Instance and method call/property access**

So, maybe doing things like these will be possible in PHP 5.4 or another future version :

```
(new foo())->bar()
(new $foo())->bar
(new $bar->y)->x
(new foo)[0]
```

Answer (score 19):

How about:

```
$obj = new Obj(); $method_result = $obj->method(); // ?
```

:P

Answer (score 19):

You can do it more universally by defining an identity function:

```
function identity($x) {
    return $x;
}

identity(new Obj)->method();
```

That way you don't need to define a function for each class.

Comment: Nice solution as it emphasizes the stupidity of this limitation :)

Answer (score 16):

No, this is not possible.
You need to assign the instance to a variable before you can call any of it's methods.

If you really wan't to do this you could use a factory as ropstah suggests:

```
class ObjFactory{
  public static function newObj(){
      return new Obj();
  }
}
ObjFactory::newObj()->method();
```

Comment: Pim's answer is correct. Alternatively you could use static functions if you do not wish to create an instance of the object

Comment: using this, we are force to use `public static function` instead of `public function`. Is recommended to use static?

Answer (score 8):

Simply we can do this

```
$method_result = (new Obj())->method();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a static factory method to produce the object:

```
ObjectFactory::NewObj()->method();
```

Comment: No need for a separate factory; a static method in the same class will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, was looking for a one-liner to accomplish this as part of a single expression for converting dates from one format to another.  I like doing this in a single line of code because it is a single logical operation.  So, this is a little cryptic, but it lets you instantiate and use a date object within a single line:

```
$newDateString = ($d = new DateTime('2011-08-30') ? $d->format('F d, Y') : '');
```

Another way to one-line the conversion of date strings from one format to another is to use a helper function to manage the OO parts of the code:

```
function convertDate($oldDateString,$newDateFormatString) {
    $d = new DateTime($oldDateString);
    return $d->format($newDateFormatString);
}

$myNewDate = convertDate($myOldDate,'F d, Y');
```

I think the object oriented approach is cool and necessary, but it can sometimes be tedious, requiring too many steps to accomplish simple operations.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is quite old as questions go but here is something I think should be mentioned:

The special class method called "__call()" can be used to create new items inside of a class.  You use it like this:

```
<?php
class test
{

function __call($func,$args)
{
    echo "I am here - $func\n";
}

}

    $a = new test();
    $a->new( "My new class" );
?>
```

Output should be:

```
I am here - new
```

Thus, you can fool PHP into making a "new" command inside of your top level class (or any class really) and put your include command in to the __call() function to include the class that you have asked for.  Of course, you would probably want to test $func to make sure it is a "new" command that was sent to the __call() command and (of course) you could have other commands also because of how __call() works.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also clone an object and call a method on the same line too:

```
(clone $image)->save('thumbnail.jpg');
```

I actually struggled find it out. I thought it could help some people.