# Is it possible to create instance and call method in one command (on the same line) in PHP?

Tags: php, object, methods, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, can you instantiate an object and call a method on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line)

Is it possible?

Normally, it requires two lines:

```
$instance = new MyClass();
$variable = $instance->method();
```

Is something like this possible in PHP?:

```
$variable = new MyClass()->method();
```

Of course, the first code is better for readability and clean code, etc., but I was just curious if you can shrink it. Maybe it could be useful, if the method returned another instance, e.g.:

```
$instance = new MyClass()->methodThatReturnsInstance();
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: Have you even tried it yourself to see if it works??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: The code new MyClass()->method() is invalid (parse error), so I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this somehow else.

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at the answer I gave to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line/1402526#1402526

Comment: In spite of what is said in the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line) I'm certain it is possible, but I can't find the incantation at the moment. Suffice to say it's ugly and not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, please close it as duplicate. I didn't see the question (probably because I searched the keyword 'instance' and the question doesn't contain it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously answered:

[In PHP, can you instantiate an object and call a method on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a static method that constructs a default instance and return it.

```
class Foo
{
     public static function instance() { return new Foo(); }
     ...
}

echo Foo::instance()->someMethod();
```

I don't really recommend this though as it's just syntactic sugar. You're only cutting out one line and losing readability.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you have asked for is available from PHP 5.4. Here is the list of new features in PHP 5.4:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

And the relevant part from the new features list:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().