# Calling method directly after new?

Tags: php

Does PHP allow to call methods off of a new object like this:

```
new CEntry( new Control() )->actuate();
```

I can pass a new object in as a parameter, as in `new Control()`. However, it does not seem to like the actuate() call.

I'm getting error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/foo/public_html/develop/foos/source/class.CEntry.php on line 4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP, can you instantiate an object and call a method on the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not until PHP 5.4, no. In PHP 5.3 and earlier, you'll have to use another variable:

```
$obj = new CEntry( new Control() );
$obj->actuate();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does PHP allow to call methods off of a new object like this:

```
new CEntry( new Control() )->actuate();
```

It does in >= PHP 5.4

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Not sure, I read about it in some PHP 5.4 release notes IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

For versions less than 5.4, you can actually use this trick by using parenthesis:

```
(new CEntry( new Control() ))->actuate();
```