# Can I use the arrow operator on a new instance of an object?

Tags: php

The following PHP code is valid:

```
$a = new MyClass();
$a->myFunction();
```

Is there a valid way to combine these two statements? My first attempt understandably results in a syntax error:

```
new MyClass()->myFunction();
```

I then added brackets around the created object, and that ran fine on PHP 5.4.17 but not on PHP 5.3.26:

```
(new MyClass())->myFunction();
```

At what point is this syntax accepted, or should I abandon this idea and just use two lines. My actual use case is more complicated and it would make the code much neater if I didn't have to keep creating single-use variables all the time.

I am unable to find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: My bad. Seems I didn't quite use the right terminology to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes directly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line) also asked here on SO.

The feature you have asked for is available from PHP 5.4. Here is the list of new features in PHP 5.4:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

And the relevant part from the new features list:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().

Answer (score 1):

```
(new MyClass())->myFunction();
```

is justfine since PHP 5.4. You can use it, but i think two-line approach is cleaner, backwards compatible with older PHP versions and won't confuse newcomming programmers who read your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Added in PHP 5.4.0. Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. `(new Foo)->bar()`.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 1):

The `(new MyClass())->myFunction()` notation is introduced in PHP 5.4 (including some other short-hand notations, see the [new features-page](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)).

One workaround (which I don't recommend to misuse this in all situations) is to have a static method in MyClass:

```
class MyClass {
    public static newInstance() {
        return new self();
    }
    public function myFunction() {}
}

MyClass::newInstance()->myFunction();
```