# Accessing class function during instantiation

Tags: php, class, oop

I've done some research and found this [SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line) and this [Php Docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)...

Now my problem is, it's not working!

My current php version is `5.4.12` which this feature that I'm after is compatible with `5.4`. I'm wondering why it's not working?

This is what I'm after and the stuff I've tried so far...

For example, we have a class of:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $var = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        // either with or without
        // return $this;
    }

    public static function newObj()
    {
        return new self;
    }

    public function setVar($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}
```

And I've tried these:

```
$obj = (new MyClass)->setVar("foo");

// or

$obj = MyClass::newObj()->setVar("foo");
```

But none work and when I get the `$obj` value using `var_dump`, it's just `null`.

**EDIT**

I've also tried and placed an `echo` inside the `__construct` to see if the class is being initialize, and it is.

Comment: You're not returning anything from `setVar()` - what value do you *expect* `$obj` to have?

Comment: ah, so i need to have `return $this;`. it works when i put that there, but why? i expect during the instantiation of the class, the object is created/returned and i just access it with `setName` and store the class with the altered name in my local `$obj` variable. so, this is not what it's really happening. thanks.

Comment: During the *instantiation*, the object is returned, but you then take it and immediately use it to call `setVar()`. Assignment to `$obj` happens only after the right side of `=` is completely evaluated, and in this case the result of that evaluation is the result of `setVar()`.

Comment: return `$this` in a setter method and assigning this in a concatenated statement to a variable holding the entire instance is obscure code. Very likely to break in the next maintenance release ...

Answer (score 2):

As `setVar` is not returning anything, the left hand site *must* be null.

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->setVar("foo");
```

will work.

Other way, but quite unusual since setters normally do not return anything:

```
...
public function setVar($var)
{
    $this->var = $var;
    return $this;
}
...

// now this will work:
$obj = (new MyClass)->setVar("foo");
```

but for me this is obscure code.

Comment: guess he wants to have chain functions maybe.

Comment: chain functions: no speed gain, but very likely to get unreadable code.

Comment: Methods returning `$this` allow for method chaining: `$some_rows = (new DatabaseQuery)->setFrom(...)->setWhere(...)->setLimit()->execute()` is readable, especially with newlines. But IMO that only works in cases where you don't need to capture the newly constructed object for future usage.

Comment: @DCoder: Agree! but I wouldn't expect a setter method to return the object in order to use this in a chain with the constructor. Your example above makes sense, there you get a result set from the last method.