# Instantiate a class object and call one of its methods

Tags: php, class, methods

I have multiple dimension arrays containing various values and would like to bring up the appropriate array or `$profile` based of the users input into a HTML form.

I have started using `array_map` , `array_filter` and closure but I'm am only new to them all so I would very much appreciate an explanation alongside your code solution to help me learn. I know there are a lot of similar questions to this but I can't seem to make sense of them.

```
<?php
$profileArray = array( 
array(  'Name' => "Toby",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Gender' => "Male",
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Cassie",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Gender' => "Female", 
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Lucy",
        'Age' => 1, 
        'Gender' => "Female", 
        ),

);

$profiles = $profileArray[1][2][3];

class profileFilter {

function get_profile_by_age ($profiles, $age){
    return array_filter ($profiles, function($data) use ($age){
    return $data->age === $age;
    });    
}
}
var_dump (get_profile_by_age ($profiles, 3));
```

When I try this in my browser I get a syntax error on `var_dump`

**EDIT:** I have fixed suggested syntax errors but still no luck. Am I calling my array correctly? I feel like I am missing a step or syntax there too.

Comment: what is the exact syntax error message?

Comment: you have missed a closing curly brace for `profileFilter ` class definition

Comment: @rsz Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: @rsz After closing that bracket as RomanPerekhrest suggested a new error has shown: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_profile_by_age() AND Notice: Undefined offset

Comment: you're missing a `}` before `var_dump` - voting close.

Comment: [In PHP, can you instantiate an object and call a method on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1402505/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// meaningless line
// $profiles = $profileArray[1][2][3];

// i don't understand for what purpose you create a class, 
// but if do, declare function as static 
// or create an object and call it by obj->function
class profileFilter {

static function get_profile_by_age ($profile, $age){
    return array_filter ($profile, function($data) use ($age){
    // $data is arrray of arrays, there is no objects there
    return $data['Age'] === $age;
    });    
}
}
var_dump (profileFilter::get_profile_by_age ($profileArray , 3));
//  now it works
```

Comment: I was using `$profiles = $profileArray[1][2][3];` to later call it here `static function get_profile_by_age ($profiles, $age)` Your code worked but can you just explain that part to me a bit clearer? Thank you for the correct code!

Comment: You need to read about classes an methods. Or don't think about that and just remove class and make usual `function get_profile_by_age(...`  without class.

Comment: Statment `$profiles = $profileArray[1][2][3];` try to set variable `$profiles` with value of item of 3d array. For example, if ` $profileArray = [ [], [[], [1,2,3,4]]]`  then `$profiles` will be 4;

Comment: If you only  want to copy array `$profiles = $profileArray;` will be enough. After this you can call `get_profile_by_age ($profile , 3);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So should it be `$profiles = $profileArray` therefore `get_profile_by_age ($profiles , 3);` with the 's' at the end? You don't define it in your code so I'm confused how it knows what `$profile` is.

Comment: I have created it as a class to use later when filtering from a HTML form, is it unnecessary?

Comment: No, it is not necessary The same as using the same name for argument of function when you are declaring it and when calling.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Really useful and I appreciate it!

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: One more thing, when your say `$data` should I change that variable to be unique to each function such as 
    `return $ageInput['Age'] === $age;`  `return $nameInput['Name'] === $name;`

Comment: when you declare a function you write any name - `function fn($a, $b)` and use this names in function. When in future you will call this function - `fn($ageInput, $nameInput);` php as if doing `$a = $ageInput;`... and then exec code of the function

Comment: Ah ok, it's all making sense now. I have another question opened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370382/php-obtaining-data-from-input-in-html-form-then-output-using-filter-array/37370642#37370642) if you would like to continue helping with this as I can't call the input from the html form.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are several errors. (Just correcting syntax errors)

```
<?php
$profileArray = array( 
array(  
      'Name' => 'Toby', //here are the ' missing
      'Age' => 3, 
      'Gender' => "Male",
     ),
...
```

I do not know if you have such classes like the 'Name' value in your array, but i assume you do not, so the names should be in quotes too.

```
$profiles = $profileArray[1][2][3];

class profileFilter {
  function get_profile_by_age ($profile, $age){
      return array_filter ($profiles, function($data) use ($age){
      return $data->age === $age;
      });
  }//here is one missing
}

var_dump(get_profile_by_age ($profiles, 3));
```

Comment: I have changed them but still no joy.