# PHP: Obtaining data from input in HTML form then output using filter_array

Tags: php, html, filter

I am trying to create a filter system basically, that gets data from input in a HTML form and then uses that data in PHP to filter existing 'profiles' from `$profileArray` , outputting whatever profiles include the user entered data/variable(s). I can not figure out how to send the user input data through my filter_array functions which, as far as I know, work from testing it using `var_dump`.

As a beginner, I can't understand $foo and $bar explanations in php.net so clear explanations are very much appreciated.

## HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="profileFilter.php" method="POST">
    <p>Age: <input type="text" name="ageChoice"></p>
    <p>Colour: <input type="text" name="colourChoice"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="catQualitiesBtn">   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## PHP

```
<?php    
    $profileArray = array( 
    array(  'Name' => "Toby",
            'Age' => 3, 
            'Colour' => "Ginger",
            ),

array(  'Name' => "Cassie",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Colour' => "Tabby",
        ),

array(  'Name' => "Lucy",
        'Age' => 1, 
        'Colour' => "Black",
        )
        );

function get_profile_by_age ($profile, $age){
    return array_filter ($profile, function($ageInput) use ($age){
    return $ageInput['Age'] === $age;
   });    
   }

 function get_profile_by_age ($profile, $colour){
    return array_filter ($profile, function($colourInput) use ($colour){
    return $colourInput['Colour'] === $colour;
  });    
  }

$ageInput = intval($_POST['ageChoice']);
$colourInput = strval($_POST['colourChoice']);

echo function get_profile_by_age ($ageInput , $age);
echo function get_profile_by_colour ($colourInput , $colour);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what your question was but i think you are not able to loop through you'r array. This loop will help you too loop through the multidimensional array. And in you array the age isnt in string, so you don't have to change the value of the user input from string to int.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="profileFilter.php" method="POST">
<p>Age: <input type="text" name="ageChoice"></p>
<p>Colour: <input type="text" name="colourChoice"></p>
<input type="submit" name="catQualitiesBtn">   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

 $profileArray = array( 
array(  'Name' => "Toby",
        'Age' => 3, 
        'Colour' => "Ginger",
        ),

   array(  'Name' => "Cassie",
    'Age' => 3, 
    'Colour' => "Tabby",
    ),

  array(  'Name' => "Lucy",
    'Age' => 1, 
    'Colour' => "Black",
    )
    );

  if (isset($_POST['ageChoice']) && isset($_POST['colourChoice'])) {
   $ageInput = $_POST['ageChoice'];
   $colourInput = $_POST['colourChoice'];

 for ($i=0; $i >=0 ; $i++) { 
        if ($profileArray[i]['Age'] == $_POST['ageChoice'] && $profileArray[i]['Colour'] == $_POST['colourChoice']) {
            echo "name -".$profileArray[i]['Name'];
            break;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the head's up on the `intval`  I actually edited it just before you sent your answer. I'm not getting an error but nothing is showing anything after I submitted the values into the HTML form? I am trying to make a filter system basically that spits back the profiles from `$profileArray` that contain the string data inputted in the HTML form.

Comment: @eainnem use the above loop

Comment: I did and it's not working. It's bringing me to a continuous loop. Also you have an extra } at the end....