# Why PHP constructors don't return a usable object?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I keep on stumbling on this PHP quirk and can't seem to explain myself why it's happening.

Why does this

```
new MyClass()->doSomething();
```

Trigger an error, while

```
(new MyClass())->doSomething();
```

and

```
$myObject = new MyClass();
$myObject->doSomething();
```

work as expected?

Is there a valid reason for needing the brackets around the constructor?

I found [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call) explaining that it was a conscious choice, but I still can't seem to understand the reason for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line

Comment: @Ananth, that doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: new MyClass() actually return a pointer on MyClass()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass()` could be a function call which returns an object whose `doSomething` method returns a string which refers to a class which you're then trying to instantiate with `new`, i.e.:

```
$className = MyClass()->doSomething();
new $className;
```

The added `()` are for syntactical disambiguation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems just a design decision: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call

Moreover works well with function call chaining (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall) and dereferencing

Here the full discussion on PHP Internals ML:
https://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg48787.html

Answer (score -1):

```
new MyClass
```

returns a pointer on MyClass object then you can access your method like that

```
(new MyClass())->func();
```

because of the pointer

here

```
new MyClass()->func();
```

you don't access the pointer, then can't use your function and that's why you get an error